# Use of IsAssignableFrom and "is" keyword in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, casting, unity-container, reflection

While trying to learn [Unity](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/07/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-app-using-unity-2-0.aspx), I keep seeing the following code for overriding `GetControllerInstance` in MVC:

```
if(!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType)) { ... }
```

this seems to me a pretty convoluted way of basically writing

```
if(controllerType is IController) { ... }
```

I appreciate there are subtle differences between `is` and `IsAssignableFrom`, ie `IsAssignableFrom` doesn't include cast conversions, but I'm struggling to understand the implication of this difference in practical scenarios.

When is it imporantant to choose `IsAssignableFrom` over `is`? What difference would it make in the `GetControllerExample`?

```
if (!typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType))
      throw new ArgumentException(...);
return _container.Resolve(controllerType) as IController;
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's not the same.

```
if(controllerType is IController)
```

would *always* evaluate to `false` since `controllerType` is always a `Type`, and a `Type` is never an `IController`.

The `is` operator is used to check whether an **instance** is compatible to a given type.

The IsAssignableFrom method is used to check whether a **Type** is compatible with a given type.

Comment: Ah ok the difference is obvious now. I should have spotted that!

Comment: So my guess is if `T` and `U` are generic types then `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(U))` is the same as `new T() is U`?

Comment: No but it would be the same as `new U() is T`.   T would be the base type. I always get tripped up by that. I just remember that `IsAssignableFrom` goes opposite of the `is` operator.

Answer (score 21):

`typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType)` tests a `Type` against the interface. The `is` operator tests an instance against the interface.

Answer (score 16):

`is` keyword is only applicable for instances while Type.IsAssignableFrom() is only applicable for types.

example of `is`

```
string str = "hello world";
if(str is String)
{
    //str instance is of type String
}
```

Note that str is an instance and not the type.

example of `IsAssignableFrom()`

```
string str = "hello world";
if(typeof(Object).IsAssignableFrom(str.GetType()))
{
    //instances of type String can be assigned to instances of type Object.
}

if(typeof(Object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string)))
{
    //instances of type String can be assigned to instances of type Object.
}
```

Note that, argument to IsAssignableFrom() is not the instance of String, it's the Type object representing String type.

Answer (score 5):

A notable difference is also that 'is' makes intuitive sense for testing inheritance or interface implementation, whereas IsAssignableFrom makes anything but sense on the face of it.  The name of the Type.IsAssignableFrom method is vague and confusing when applied to testing inheritance or detecting interface implementations.  The following wrapper for these purposes would make for much more intuitive, readable application code:

```
    public static bool CanBeTreatedAsType(this Type CurrentType, Type TypeToCompareWith)
    {
        // Always return false if either Type is null
        if (CurrentType == null || TypeToCompareWith == null)
            return false;

        // Return the result of the assignability test
        return TypeToCompareWith.IsAssignableFrom(CurrentType);
    }
```

Then, one can have more understandable client syntax like:

```
    bool CanBeTreatedAs = typeof(SimpleChildClass).CanBeTreatedAsType(typeof(SimpleClass));
    CanBeTreatedAs = typeof(SimpleClass).CanBeTreatedAsType(typeof(IDisposable));
```

The advantage of this method instead of the 'is' keyword is that it can be used at run-time to test unknown, arbitrary Types, whereas the 'is' keyword (and a generic Type parameter) requires compile-time knowledge of specific Types.

Comment: I don't see how `IsAssignableFrom` is completely unintuitive. In a polymorphic type system, any type can be assigned a value from any of its subtypes, i.e. you can do something like: `SimpleBaseClass myVar = new SimpleChildClass()`.  `IsAssignableFrom` tells you whether such a polymorphic assignment would be legal, and thus whether one type is a subtype-or-equal-to another.