# "is" c# multiple options

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
return (
      Page is WebAdminPriceRanges ||
      Page is WebAdminRatingQuestions
);
```

Is there a way to do it like:

```
return (
    Page is WebAdminPriceRanges || WebAdminRatingQuestions
);
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, and it's meaningless.

Comment: The is operator takes two operands in C#. That is really all there is to say. However, with a bit of fancy, "could be" similar to `IsAnyOf(x, myListOfTypes)` (it would use `IsAssignableFrom` internally though, not `is`.) In fact, I have seen this done before on SO. (Try searching for `IsAssingableFrom`.)

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013694/use-of-isassignablefrom-and-is-keyword-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The first way you specified is the only reasonable way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

No, such syntax is not possible. The [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) operator requires 2 operands, the first is an instance of an object and the second is a type.

You could use `GetType()`:

```
return new[] { typeof(WebAdminPriceRanges), typeof(WebAdminRatingQuestions) }.Contains(Page.GetType());
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really. You can look for the `Type` instance inside a collection, but that doesn't account for the implicit conversions that [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) performs; for example, `is` also detects if the type is a *base* of the instance it operates on.

Example:

```
var types = new[] {typeof(WebAdminPriceRanges), typeof(WebAdminRatingQuestions)};

// this will return false if Page is e.g. a WebAdminBase
var is1 = types.Any(t => t == Page.GetType());

// while this will return true
var is2 = Page is WebAdminPriceRanges || Page is WebAdminRatingQuestions;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, C# is not the English language, you cannot omit one operand from a two-operand operation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do this.

if your *intent* is return a Page, **only** if it is of type `WebAdminPriceRanges` *or* `WebAdminRatingQuestions` , you can easily do it with if.

For example:

```
if(Page is WebAdminPriceRanges || Page is WebAdminRatingQuestions)
   return Page;
return null;
```

Assuming that Page is a *reference* type or at least *nullable value* type

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are true, but while I'm not sure where is fits in operator precedence. If the is operator is lower than the logical-or operator, you would be or-ing two classes together which is meaningless.