# Difference between "is" and "IsAssignableFrom" C#

Tags: c#, interface, reflection

What's the difference between:

```
typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Class));
```

and

```
typeof(Class) is IInterface
```

?

Edit: for context, my function is something like this:

```
public static List<T> GetAllInstancesOfType<T>() where T:Entity
{
  List<T> l = new List<T>();

  if (typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) //or (typeof(T) is IMyInterface)
     foreach(Entity e in List1) if (e is T) l.Add(e as T);

  else foreach (Entity e in List2) if (e is T) l.Add(e as T);

  return l;
}
```

Comment: This might be useful: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013694/use-of-isassignablefrom-and-is-keyword-in-c-sharp

Comment: There's only a couple of interfaces where the second will return true -- `ICustomAttributeProvider` and `IReflect`.

Answer (score 14):

They are similar-looking but conceptually very different. The former answers the question "if I had a *variable* of this type, could I assign to it a *value* of that type?"

The latter answers the question "can this *actual value* be converted to this type via reference or boxing conversion?"

In the latter case, the actual object is an object of type `Type`, not an object of type `Class`.  Make sure you understand the difference between:

```
Type t = typeof(Class);
Class c = new Class();
bool b1 = t is IInterface;
bool b2 = c is IInterface;
```

The first asks "can the `Type` object be converted to the interface?" and the second asks "can the `Class` object be converted to the interface?"

Comment: I'm writing a GetAllInstancesOfType<T>() style function, and inferring information of which list to look in for Ts from the interface T implements (i.e. if T does implement interface I look in list A, if not look in list B). Since all I'm checking is "does T implement I", from your answer I'm talking about whether a variable T could be assigned a value of type I, and not conversion from I to T - and therefore I should use option 1?

Comment: @Haighstrom: I don't understand your scenario well enough to make a recommendation, but something seems strange about it. If you want to know if a given `Type` represents a type that implements a particular interface then why on earth are you checking for *variable assignability*?  What do variables have to do with it? If you want to know if a type implements an interface then just ask the type for a list of its implemented interfaces! Remember, *assignability* and *implementation* need not be the same thing.

Comment: An instance of a type which implements `IEnumerable<string>` is *assignable* to a variable of type `IEnumerable<object>`, even if it does not *implement* that type. So which do you care about, assignability, or implementation?

Comment: I've added an example to the original post for context. Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: @Haighstrom: Your approach raises a flag in my mind: any time you make a decision based on the specific details of the argument given to a generic type parameter, you're writing code that is not really in the spirit of generics. But I am actually more concerned that you understand the difference between a type object and an instance of that type. The questions "are all animals of a given type -- say, tigers -- also mammals?" and "is this specific animal -- a tiger -- a mammal?" have the same answer: yes. The question "is the abstract notion of 'tiger' a mammal?" is not the same question.

Comment: Think of the idea you get in your head when you think of the class of all tigers: that idea does not give birth to live young, have hair, or make its own milk. That *idea* is not a mammal.  The *description* of a tiger is not a mammal; a *tiger* is a mammal. That's what you're asking when you say `typeof(T) is IFoo` -- the answer is almost certainly going to be "false", because *a description of all Ts does not necessarily have any property in common with an actual T*.

Answer (score 3):

Some differences:

A: With IsAssignableFrom you don't need any object instances, (only System.Type objects), which is very useful during reflection.

B: With the **is** keyword get some compile-time hints if the types are always/never compatible (at least with resharper)

C: They are kind of the opposites. IsAssignableFrom checks if an object of the type passed as argument can be assigned to a variable of the other type. The **is** keyword checks if the object on the left side of the keyword can be assigned to a variable of the type to the right of the keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`typeof(Class) is IInterface` will always evaluate to `false`, because the type of `typeof(Class)` is `RuntimeType`. The right way to use is on an instance of the given class, e.g.

```
Class c = // something
bool isIt = c is IInterface;
```

`is` should be used when you want to know whether a value is convertible to a type that is known at compile time.

`IsAssignableFrom` should be used when one or both of the types are only known at runtime.  E.g. `someType.IsAssignableFrom(someOtherType)`. If both types are known at compile time, e.g. `typeof(IInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Class));`, you can know the answer by looking up the definition of `Class`, and it doesn't really make sense to check it at runtime.